# Find $y$ that minimizes a sum of squares

Tags: optimization, discrete-optimization

Let $x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n$ be $n$ positive, distinct real numbers such that $x_1 < x_2 < \cdots < x_n$. I'd like to find some $y \in \{ x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n \}$ such that

$$\sum_{x_i \le y} \left(x_i - \frac{1}{L}\sum_{x_j \le y} x_j\right)^2 + \sum_{x_i > y} \left(x_i - \frac{1}{R}\sum_{x_j > y} x_j\right)^2$$

is minimized. Here, $L$ is the total number of $x_i$'s such that $x_i \le y$, and $R$ is the total number of $x_i$'s such that $x_i > y$.

I apologize if this is a trivial question, but I couldn't figure it out. I thought the answer might be mean or median of $\{ x_1, x_2 \dots, x_n \}$, but some simulations proved my idea to be wrong.

Comment: Can you precise what you mean by to find $y$? Are you looking for a closed form or an algorithm ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering

Comment: That is not at all trivial. You can easily find such an $y$ for your case, but it is hard to make any precise statements about such a $y$, as it will depend strongly on the distribution of the $x_i$. Your question can be rephrased to be: For a set of observations ${x_i}$ find a partition $S_1\cup S_2$, so that $\mathrm{var} S_1 + \mathrm{var} S_2$ is minimal.

Comment: @Lazy "You can easily find such an $y$ for your case" How?

Comment: @d.k.o. I am aware of that. However, I am searching in a much smaller space. I am not consider all possible partitions.

Comment: @TJnFvYLDu3 There is a trivial algorithm by simply running $y$ through all possible values. Using Steiner’s theorem you can get this down to $\Theta(n)$. The algorithm would look like this: Let $A:=0$, $B=\sum x_i^2$, $C=0$, $D=\sum x_i$, $N=0$, $M=n$. Then your target is given by $A - B^2/N + C - D^2/M$. For each $x_i$ in ascending order increase $A$ and decrease $C$ by $x_i^2$ and increase $B$ and decrease $D$ by $x_i$. Increase $I$ and decrease $J$ by $1$. In each pass compare the current target to the best so far, and save $I$ for the best target so far.

Comment: @TJnFvYLDu3 You might be able to improve this with bisecting or somthing, but this algorithm is just slightly more expensive then calculating the variance.

Comment: Do you agree with my edits?

Answer (score 0):

We can formulate a continuous version

$$
F(y) = \int_{0}^{y} \left(f(x)-\frac{\int_{0}^{x} f(\zeta) \, d\zeta}{L}\right)^2 \, dx+\int_{y}^{x_n} \left(f(x)-\frac{\int_{y}^{x} f(\zeta) \,
   d\zeta}{R}\right)^2 \, dx
$$

and then specify $f(x)$. For instance, for $f(x) = x$ we have

$$
F(y) = \frac{y^5}{20 L^2}-\frac{y^4}{4 L}-\frac{20 R^2 \left(y^3-125\right)+15 R \left(y^2-25\right)^2+\left(8 y^2+45
   y+75\right) (y-5)^3}{60 R^2}+\frac{y^3}{3}
$$

now assuming $x_n=5,L=R=1$

[image]

Follows a MATHEMATICA script which is a discrete version

```
n = 50;
dx = 5/n;
X = Table[(dx k), {k, 0, n}];
U = Table[(dx k), {k, 0, n}];
resy = Table[Sum[(X[[j]] - 1/L Sum[X[[k]] dx, {k, 1, j}])^2 dx, {j, 1, nu}] + Sum[(X[[j]] - 1/R Sum[X[[k]] dx, {k, nu + 1, j}])^2 dx, {j, nu + 1, n + 1}], {nu, 1, n + 1}] /. {L -> 1, R -> 1};
res = {U, resy} // Transpose;
ListPlot[res ]
```

[image]

NOTE

`dx`was introduced in the script to have comparable results.